# How do I get the current (sauce) browser from within an rspec example?

Tags: rspec, selenium-webdriver, saucelabs

I am running tests on sauce labs. I have tried `Sauce.get_config[:browser].to_s` in an after block but it returns an empty string.

I'm wondering if I need to put it in `sauce_helper.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

If using Capybara then `Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.browser` will return the current browser. Interesting that `page.driver.browser.browser` seems to works as well.